# Getting a "no module named flask" error when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am having trouble deploying my app to heroku. I'm starting the server from a file called app.py in the root directory, and I have installled Flask in a venv in a folder called flask and the error I'm getting is "no module named flask"

the heroku logs are as follows:

```
2015-04-21T09:18:36.128263+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2015-04-21T09:18:36.135666+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named flask
    2015-04-21T09:18:36.135349+00:00 app[web.1]:     from flask import Flask, url_for
    2015-04-21T09:18:37.102956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2015-04-21T09:18:37.072990+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2015-04-21T10:03:46.376428+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2015-04-21T10:03:48.581259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python app.py --log-file=-`
    2015-04-21T10:03:50.464852+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    2015-04-21T10:03:50.464953+00:00 app[web.1]:     from flask import Flask, url_for
    2015-04-21T10:03:50.465130+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named flask
```

and my app.py is:

```
#!flask/bin/python
import os
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.restless import APIManager
from flask.ext.assets import Environment, Bundle
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
from marshmallow import Schema
from marshmallow import fields
import flask 
import json

flashcards = Flask(__name__)

flashcards.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://localhost/flashcards'
db = SQLAlchemy(flashcards)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    decks = db.relationship('Deck', backref='users')

class Deck(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'decks'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    cards = db.relationship('Card', backref='deck')
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), index=True)
    last_session = db.Column(db.BigInteger) 
    session_num = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)

class Card(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cards'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    question = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    answer = db.Column(db.Text)
    deck_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('decks.id'), index=True)
    box_id = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0) 

db.create_all()

manager = flask.ext.restless.APIManager(flashcards, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)


manager.create_api(User, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
manager.create_api(Deck, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT','DELETE'])
manager.create_api(Card, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT','DELETE'])


@flashcards.route('/')
def root():
    return flashcards.send_static_file('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    flashcards.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

EDIT:

requirements.txt

```
alembic==0.7.5.post2
aniso8601==0.92
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Assets==0.10
Flask-Migrate==1.3.1
Flask-RESTful==0.3.2
Flask-Restless==0.17.0
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
gunicorn==19.3.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
Mako==1.0.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
marshmallow==1.2.4
mimerender==0.5.5
psycopg2==2.6
python-dateutil==2.4.2
python-mimeparse==0.1.4
pytz==2015.2
six==1.9.0
SQLAlchemy==0.9.9
webassets==0.10.1
Werkzeug==0.10.4
```

Heroku build output

```
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Deleting 4 files matching .slugignore patterns.
remote: -----> Removing .DS_Store files
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing runtime (python-2.7.9)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
remote:        Collecting alembic==0.7.5.post2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading alembic-0.7.5.post2.tar.gz (616kB)
remote:        Collecting aniso8601==0.92 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading aniso8601-0.92.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz (544kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask-Assets==0.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading Flask-Assets-0.10.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting Flask-Migrate==1.3.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading Flask-Migrate-1.3.1.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting Flask-RESTful==0.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading Flask_RESTful-0.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting Flask-Restless==0.17.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading Flask-Restless-0.17.0.tar.gz (42kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask-Script==2.0.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
remote:          Downloading Flask-Script-2.0.5.tar.gz (42kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
remote:          Downloading Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.0.tar.gz (93kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-19.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (110kB)
remote:        Collecting itsdangerous==0.24 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
remote:          Downloading itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46kB)
remote:        Collecting Jinja2==2.7.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
remote:          Downloading Jinja2-2.7.3.tar.gz (378kB)
remote:        Collecting Mako==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
remote:          Downloading Mako-1.0.1.tar.gz (473kB)
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==0.23 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting marshmallow==1.2.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
remote:          Downloading marshmallow-1.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42kB)
remote:        Collecting mimerender==0.5.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading mimerender-0.5.5.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
remote:          Downloading psycopg2-2.6.tar.gz (367kB)
remote:        Collecting python-dateutil==2.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
remote:          Downloading python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (188kB)
remote:        Collecting python-mimeparse==0.1.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
remote:          Downloading python-mimeparse-0.1.4.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting pytz==2015.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
remote:          Downloading pytz-2015.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (476kB)
remote:        Collecting six==1.9.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
remote:          Downloading six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting SQLAlchemy==0.9.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
remote:          Downloading SQLAlchemy-0.9.9.tar.gz (4.2MB)
remote:        Collecting webassets==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 23))
remote:          Downloading webassets-0.10.1.tar.gz (167kB)
remote:        Collecting Werkzeug==0.10.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
remote:          Downloading Werkzeug-0.10.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (293kB)
remote:        Installing collected packages: Werkzeug, webassets, SQLAlchemy, six, pytz, python-mimeparse, python-dateutil, psycopg2, mimerender, marshmallow, MarkupSafe, Mako, Jinja2, itsdangerous, gunicorn, Flask-SQLAlchemy, Flask-Script, Flask-Restless, Flask-RESTful, Flask-Migrate, Flask-Assets, Flask, aniso8601, alembic
remote:        
remote:          Running setup.py install for webassets
remote:            Installing webassets script to /app/.heroku/python/bin
remote:          Running setup.py install for SQLAlchemy
remote:            building 'sqlalchemy.cprocessors' extension
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/processors.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/processors.o
remote:            gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/processors.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy/cprocessors.s
remote:            building 'sqlalchemy.cresultproxy' extension
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/resultproxy.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/resultproxy.o
remote:            gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/resultproxy.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy/cresultproxy.so
remote:            building 'sqlalchemy.cutils' extension
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/utils.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/utils.o
remote:            gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/utils.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy/cutils.so
remote:        
remote:        
remote:          Running setup.py install for python-mimeparse
remote:        
remote:          Running setup.py install for psycopg2
remote:            building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/error_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/lib -lpq -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
remote:          Running setup.py install for mimerender
remote:        
remote:          Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe
remote:            building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension
remote:            gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python2.7 -c markupsafe/_speedups.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/markupsafe/_speedups.o
remote:            gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/markupsafe/_speedups.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/markupsafe/_speedups.so
remote:          Running setup.py install for Mako
remote:            Installing mako-render script to /app/.heroku/python/bin
remote:          Running setup.py install for Jinja2
remote:          Running setup.py install for itsdangerous
remote:          Compiling /tmp/pip-build-2z5fcv/gunicorn/gunicorn/workers/_gaiohttp.py
remote:          
remote:        
remote:          Running setup.py install for Flask-SQLAlchemy
remote:          Running setup.py install for Flask-Script
remote:          Running setup.py install for Flask-Restless
remote:        
remote:          Running setup.py install for Flask-Migrate
remote:          Running setup.py install for Flask-Assets
remote:          Running setup.py install for Flask
remote:          Running setup.py install for aniso8601
remote:          Running setup.py install for alembic
remote:            Installing alembic script to /app/.heroku/python/bin
remote:        Successfully installed Flask-0.10.1 Flask-Assets-0.10 Flask-Migrate-1.3.1 Flask-RESTful-0.3.2 Flask-Restless-0.17.0 Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.0 Flask-Script-2.0.5 Jinja2-2.7.3 Mako-1.0.1 MarkupSafe-0.23 SQLAlchemy-0.9.9 Werkzeug-0.10.4 alembic-0.7.5.post2 aniso8601-0.92 gunicorn-19.3.0 itsdangerous-0.24 marshmallow-1.2.4 mimerender-0.5.5 psycopg2-2.6 python-dateutil-2.4.2 python-mimeparse-0.1.4 pytz-2015.2 six-1.9.0 webassets-0.10.1
remote: 
remote: -----> Preparing static assets
remote:        Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run:
remote:        $ heroku run python ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 57.0MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v5
```

Comment: Your shebang `#!flask/bin/python` looks weird.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a `requirements.txt` with your dependencies as described in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip .

Comment: Hi my requirements.txt file is as follows:                     alembic==0.7.5.post2
aniso8601==0.92
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Assets==0.10
Flask-Migrate==1.3.1
Flask-RESTful==0.3.2
Flask-Restless==0.17.0
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
gunicorn==19.3.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
Mako==1.0.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
marshmallow==1.2.4
mimerender==0.5.5
psycopg2==2.6
python-dateutil==2.4.2
python-mimeparse==0.1.4
pytz==2015.2
six==1.9.0
SQLAlchemy==0.9.9
webassets==0.10.1
Werkzeug==0.10.4

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't use the virutalenv you use locally. Don't commit it to source control or push it to heroku. Use the `requirements.txt` file to list your projects dependencies.

Comment: added requirements.txt above

Comment: Why do you have `#!flask/bin/python` at the top of your file?

Comment: I took that off, don;t know why I had it there, same problems though

Comment: When you deploy the app to Heroku, you should see the output of it creating the virutalenv and installing the dependencies. Do you see that?

Comment: No, I didn't see that, I'll post the output